# POST json to another url

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've a problem as I need to send some json to a url. When I send all my json and token to the page.

Then there will be no content JSON value into the system.

I have checked up on whether there is some content and it is there, but it sends just do not like json values.

```
string apiKeyToken = model.reepaytoken; // TOKEN HERE.

string URLLink = APIClassPay.HelperPay.CreateCustomerURL;//URL to send it json to.

WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //JSON coming here!
var JSONCustomer = APIClassPay.HelperPay.CreateCustomer(model.Brugernavn, model.Adresse, model.Byen, model.Postnr.ToString(), model.Mobil.ToString(), model.Fornavn, model.Efternavn);
client.Headers.Add("text/json", JSONCustomer);
client.Headers.Set("X-Auth-Token", apiKeyToken);
string reply = client.DownloadString(URLLink);
```

When I blow my json looks like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult information(BuyMedlemskabViewModel model)
{
    DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
    var Pric = db.PriceValues.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == model.HiddenIdMedlemskab);
    if (Pric != null)
    {
        string _OrderValue = DateTime.Now.Year + Helper.Settings.PlanValue();
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.OrderId] = _OrderValue;

        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.FakturaId] = model.HiddenIdMedlemskab;

        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.fornavn] = model.Fornavn;
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.efternavn] = model.Efternavn;
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.Adresse] = model.Adresse;
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.Post] = model.Postnr;
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.Byen] = model.Byen;
        Session[HelperTextClass.HelperText.SessionName.Mobil] = model.Mobil;


        string apiKeyToken = model.reepaytoken;.

        string URLLink = APIClassPay.HelperPay.CreateCustomerURL;//URL to send it json to.

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //JSON coming here!
        var JSONCustomer = APIClassPay.HelperPay.CreateCustomer(model.Brugernavn, model.Adresse, model.Byen, model.Postnr.ToString(), model.Mobil.ToString(), model.Fornavn, model.Efternavn);
        client.Headers.Add("text/json", JSONCustomer);
        client.Headers.Set("X-Auth-Token", apiKeyToken);
        string reply = client.DownloadString(URLLink);


    }
    return RedirectToAction("information");
}
```

EDIT - Update (ERROR HERE):

[image]

ReePay API reference: https://docs.reepay.com/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few things, you'll have to fix:

First of all you're obviously trying to *create* a ressource (usually a POST or PUT, speaking in [REST-words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) but you're using `WebClient`'s `DownloadString`-method [which performs a GET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). So I think you should probably use a POST or PUT instead but which one to chose exactly depends on the web service you're contacting.

Then you seem to have mistaken the `Content-Type`-header and tried to pack the payload in there. The payload - your customer JSON - will have to be put into the request's body.

Based on your previous questions I assume the service you're trying to contact is either [PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081982/key-and-value-in-json) or [QuickPay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229183/send-json-data-to-another-url-after-youve-got-it-back-from-my-own-url). To further help you with this question, it'd be helpful if you could specify which one you use.

If it's QuickPay, please notice that there's an [official .NET client](https://github.com/QuickPay/quickpay-dotnet-client) which you could use instead of using `WebClient` on you own.

But anyway for making HTTP requests I'd suggest you to use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) in favor of `WebClient`. You'd generally do it in a way like this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
         APIClassPay.HelperPay.CreateCustomerURL); 
    request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", apiKeyToken); 
    request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.Content = new StringContent(JSONCustomer);

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you clarified in a comment, the service you're using is Reepay. If you take a look at the documentation of the [create customer method](https://docs.reepay.com/api/#create-customer), you can see, that the necessary HTTP method is POST. So the code snippet above should generally fit.

Regarding the compilation error you faced, I updated the code-snipped above. There was a mistake in the variable names I chose. Please note, that you dropped the keyword `await` as I can see from your screenshot. Please re-enter it. If the compiler complains about it, it's very likely that the .NET framework version of your project is less than 4.5 which is necessary to use async/await.

So you should update your project's .NET framework version at best to version 4.6.1 as Microsoft [recently announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) that support for 4.5 and others is discontinued. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.140).aspx) on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sorry I answer a little late. But I do not Quickpay or paypal. The two solutions can not cope with my requirements of the region for membership on my website.

I am aware that they have something on Github, but they do not offer it that I can use the membership on my website.

I had just post and google me forward at all possible ways to find a solution that I think there seemed straightforward.

Ang your code then gives the error HTTPClient and said users I do not await. Unfortunately.

Comment: Well, then can you tell which service you are trying to use instead? Is there a public api reference? What's the error you're getting with HttpClient? The keyword await is unknown? You can fix that by updating the .NET framework version of your project.

Comment: i can see its, Thanks for u answer. I have .Net Framework 4.6.

Comment: Are you able to compile now or do you face any other errors?

Comment: Nop, after i delete await it seems that it works. and thank you for your help !. Hope you will give me a +1 for the issue.